# How to decrease the page margin in an algorithm?

Tags: margins, algorithmicx

I'm writing the pseudocode of an algorithm, however, I'm using a template with big margins. I wanted to increase the space occupied by the algorithm so all the comments can fit in one line only. So far I have this:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \ForAll{pixels k} 
        \State $f_k\gets 0$
        \ForAll{pulses p}
            \State $R\gets || a_k - v_p ||$ \Comment{calculate distance from platform to pixel}
            \State $bin\gets \lfloor (R - R0)/\Delta R \rfloor$ \Comment{range bin (integer)}
            \If{$bin \in [0, N_bp - 2]$} 
                \State $w\gets \lfloor (R - R0)/\Delta R \rfloor - bin$ \Comment{interpolation weight}          
                \State $s\gets (1 - w)\cdot g(p, bin) + w \cdot g(p, bin + 1)$ \Comment{data sampled using linear interpolation}
                \State $f_k\gets f_k + e^{j \cdot ku \cdot R}$ \Comment{add pulse's contribution to the pixel}         
            \EndIf                
        \EndFor
    \EndFor    
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Backprojection algorithm pseudocode. \\ \textbf{Source:} PERFECT Manual Suite \cite{perfect2013}.}
\label{alg-bp}
\end{algorithm}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I increase the horizontal size occupied by the algorithm?

Thank you.

Comment: The `adjustwidth` from   `changepage` can be helpful.

Comment: @Bernard that's exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks awkward, but you can do it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth+5em}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \ForAll{pixels $k$}
          \State $f_k \gets 0$
          \ForAll{pulses $p$}
            \State $R \gets || a_k - v_p ||$ \Comment{calculate distance from platform to pixel}
            \State $b \gets \lfloor (R - R0)/\Delta R \rfloor$ \Comment{range bin (integer)}
            \If{$b \in [0, N_b p - 2]$}
              \State $w \gets \lfloor (R - R0)/\Delta R \rfloor - b$ \Comment{interpolation weight}
              \State $s \gets (1 - w) \cdot g(p, b) + w \cdot g(p, b + 1)$ \Comment{data sampled using linear interpolation}
              \State $f_k \gets f_k + e^{j \cdot k u \cdot R}$ \Comment{add pulse's contribution to the pixel}
            \EndIf                
          \EndFor
        \EndFor    
      \end{algorithmic}
      \caption[Backprojection algorithm pseudocode]
        {Backprojection algorithm pseudocode. \\
          \textbf{Source:} PERFECT Manual Suite \cite{perfect2013}.}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{perfect2013} Author, title.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

You can set the `algorithm` using the `[H]`ere option, which allows you to box it. In turn, this allows you to adjust the margins; above I've added `5em` to the total width (or `2.5em` on either side, since the `\makebox` centres its contents).

The algorithm is still allowed to float, since the `algorithm` box is placed inside a floating `figure` environment.

---

I'd be more inclined to adjust the pseudocode and stacking some of the elements to create more room (either the pseudocode, or the comment):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}[!th]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \ForAll{pixels $k$}
      \State $f_k \gets 0$
      \ForAll{pulses $p$}
        \State $R \gets || a_k - v_p ||$ \Comment{calculate distance from platform to pixel}
        \State $b \gets \lfloor (R - R0)/\Delta R \rfloor$ \Comment{range bin (integer)}
        \If{$b \in [0, N_b p - 2]$}
          \State $w \gets \lfloor (R - R0)/\Delta R \rfloor - b$ \Comment{interpolation weight}
          \State $s \gets \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
            (1 - w) \cdot g(p, b) \\
            {} + w \cdot g(p, b + 1)
          \end{array}$ \Comment{data sampled using linear interpolation}
          \State $f_k \gets f_k + e^{j \cdot k u \cdot R}$ \Comment{add pulse's contribution to the pixel}
        \EndIf                
      \EndFor
    \EndFor    
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption[Backprojection algorithm pseudocode]
    {Backprojection algorithm pseudocode. \\
      \textbf{Source:} PERFECT Manual Suite \cite{perfect2013}.}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{perfect2013} Author, title.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```